# wxWidgets 2.9.1 what file replaced wxmswd.lib?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm currently working through the 3dbuzz.com c++ complete videos. In the video which uses a much older version of wxWidgets it says to include wxmswd.lib, this file however does not exist and must have been replaced with something else can anyone tell me what to include instead???

Comment: In C++, you _include_ headers, and _link_ to libraries. Do you mean "include <wxmswd.h>" or "link to wxmswd.lib" ?

Comment: Never heard of it, so I doubt you need it.  What happens when you build your application?  Do you get compiler errors ( missing #include ) or linker errors ( missing library )?  Post the error messages and we can try to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I ment linking the libs.  After long time searching I found that the new file for wxWidgets is

wxmsw29ud_core.lib   replace the 29 with 28 if your using wxWidgets with 2.8.x versions.